# getPackageManager() always return null

Tags: android

I try to launch another app in my app

There is 2 methods I have tried.

**Method 1**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.b_app", "com.b_app.MainActivity");
    intent.setComponent(componentName);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Method 2**

```
        Intent intent =  getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.b_app");
        if (intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
        }
        else Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Method 1** gives me error :

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.b_app/com.b_app.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

**Method 2** the Toast shows Error (my else condition),meaning getPackageManager() returns null..

My Manifest in b_app

```
   <activity android:name="com.b_app.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and I'm pretty sure the b_app is installed in my smartphone..

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the Toast shows Error (my else condition),meaning getPackageManager() returns null

No. You would be getting a `NullPointerException` in that case. In your case, `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` is returning `null`.

That, plus your other symptoms, suggests that you do not have an application whose `applicationId` is `com.b_app` installed on this device.

Comment: ok... I check my applicationId in b_app ,and which is com.xxxx.xxxx , so com.b_app has edit to com.xxxx.xxxx ?

Comment: @achicn3: Yes. The value that you use for the `ComponentName` and for `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` needs to be the `applicationId` of the other app.

Comment: @CommonsWare you saved me man

Answer (score 0):

There is a little chance to meet in my sitution..
One of my app was returned null for "getLaunchIntentForPackage"   and I was recognize My app is not shown in Device Although  it is installed.. 
Recently I implement Firebase Dynamic... And my application manifest configured as wrongly

Here is wrong  one :

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

 </intent-filter>
```

Correct one is

```
  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            </intent-filter>
```

If you implement wrongly your application manifest, User cant install your app... because Google Play "Open"  button app is geting invisible